# Can someone explain same function's different behaviour under differnt user in oracle?

Tags: oracle, function, synonym

I have a package called A and A has function doSomething();

user x is the owner of A.
user y has a synonym testSyn which points to x.A;

Logged in as x and executed function doSomething() is returning true but When 
logged in as user y and executed the function like testSyn.doSomething(), it returns false for the same value.

Could someone please explain why this happens?

Comment: It is checking for varchar data's availability in a table of x.

Comment: And do both users have the exact same access to that table (and are they indeed seeing the same table)?

Comment: How have you defined `testSyn`, maybe thats the culprit

Comment: can you post the code? you can obstruct the sensitive information and maintain the basic ideea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the procedure's definition. If it's something like `PROCEDURE a AUTHID CURRENT_USER` then it will execute with the [current user's permissions and name resolution](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/subprograms.htm#i18574). If the procedure uses views that take user privileges into account (such as `user_objects`), that could explain the different result.

---

Comment response: You're making the wrong distinction. Imagine that you write a procedure that returns the `object_name` of the first row from `user_objects`. That procedure is owned by `schema_owner` and `schema_invoker` has permission to execute it. If the procedure is defined without `AUTHID CURRENT_USER`, it will return an object name for an object in the `schema_owner` schema.  The same procedure with `AUTHID CURRENT_USER` will return an object name from the `schema_invoker` schema instead.  This has nothing to do with execution privileges.

I don't know that this is the source of your problem, but it's a good candidate and it's easy to check (just look at the procedure definition found in the package specification).

Comment: I am able to execute that function means that user is having privilege to execution. Still output differs.

Comment: @Katturaja: @Allan is right on target. Just because you have granted `EXECUTE` privileges on your package to user Y does not necessarily mean user Y has privileges on objects referenced in your package. If the package _or_ procedure has AUTHID CURRENT_USER specified then user Y needs SELECT, UPDATE etc. grants on _all_ referenced tables as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're able to execute that function but you might not have access rights to all the objects the function references. For starters, I'd try to figure out which DB objects your function accesses and try to access those from a tool like sqlplus to verify